# Android Message Delivery

Tags: android

My application is sending different messages to different Numbers every 10 minutes... if message delivered it must not sending messages again otherwise send it again... my problem is in the delivery part, how it understand that which SMS delivered...

MessageID is Unique for each messages, i tried to use it but it didnt work...

this is my sendSMS method:

```
private void sendSMS(String phoneNumber, String message, final int MessageID)
    {      
        final String SMS_SEND_ACTION = "CTS_SMS_SEND_ACTION";
        final String SMS_DELIVERY_ACTION = "CTS_SMS_DELIVERY_ACTION";

        //---when SMS send---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    {
                        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "پیغام ارسال شد.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                       // DataAccess.UpdateTblMessageSend (getBaseContext(), MessageID ,1);
                        break;
                    }
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Generic failure", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "No service", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Null PDU", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Radio off", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                }   
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(SMS_SEND_ACTION)); //SENT

        //---when SMS delivered---
        registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver(){
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
                switch (getResultCode())
                {
                    case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                    { 
                        //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "پیغام دلیور شد.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        Log.i("DELIVERED:", "Context: " + arg0 + "--- ID:  " + MessageID); 
                        DataAccess.UpdateTblMessageSend (getBaseContext(), MessageID, 2);
                        break;
                    }
                    case Activity.RESULT_CANCELED:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "SMS not delivered", 
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;                  
                }
            }

        }, new IntentFilter(SMS_DELIVERY_ACTION)); //DELIVERED

        SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
        ArrayList<String> parts =sms.divideMessage(message);

        ArrayList<PendingIntent> sentIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>();
        ArrayList<PendingIntent> deliveryIntents = new ArrayList<PendingIntent>(); 

        for (int i = 0; i < parts.size(); i++)
        {
            sentIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMS_SEND_ACTION), 0));
            deliveryIntents.add(PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(SMS_DELIVERY_ACTION), 0));
        }
        sms.sendMultipartTextMessage(phoneNumber,null, parts, sentIntents, deliveryIntents);              
    }
```

Comment: [check this](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/sending-sms-in-background-from-an-android-application/)

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String ACTION_SMS_SENT = "SMS_SENT";
public static String ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED = "SMS_DELIVERED";
public static final String ExtraStamp = "stamp";
public static final String ExtraNum = "num";
public static final String ExtraOPN = "opn";
public static final String ExtraPN = "pn";
public static final String ExtraName = "name";

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SMS_SENT + num);
    sendIntent.putExtra(ExtraStamp, stamp);
    sendIntent.putExtra(ExtraNum, num);
    sendIntent.putExtra(ExtraPN, pn);
    sendIntent.putExtra(ExtraOPN, opn);
    sendIntent.putExtra(ExtraName, name); 

    Intent DeliveredIntent = new Intent(ACTION_SMS_DELIVERED + num);
    DeliveredIntent.putExtra(ExtraStamp, stamp);
    DeliveredIntent.putExtra(ExtraNum, num);
    DeliveredIntent.putExtra(ExtraPN, pn);
    DeliveredIntent.putExtra(ExtraOPN, opn);
    DeliveredIntent.putExtra(ExtraName, name);



    PendingIntent piSent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0, sendIntent,
            PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    PendingIntent piDelivered = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(c, 0,
            DeliveredIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

 smsManager.sendTextMessage(pn, null, message, piSent, piDelivered);
```

and in receiver

```
    String action = intent.getAction();
    Bundle extra = intent.getExtras();
    String stamp = (String) extra.get(send_sms.ExtraStamp);
    int num = extra.getInt(send_sms.ExtraNum);
    String opn = extra.getString(send_sms.ExtraOPN);
    String pn = extra.getString(send_sms.ExtraPN);
    String name = extra.getString(send_sms.ExtraName);
    ContactSendDBHandler db = new ContactSendDBHandler(context);

    if (action.equals(send_sms.ACTION_SMS_SENT + num)) 
        switch (getResultCode()) {
            case Activity.RESULT_OK:

          }
```